# Finding max/min values corresponding to certain keys in text file

Tags: python, max

I am trying to find the max and min for values in a text file corresponding to certain categories. My data file can be modeled in columns and rows like this:

catA 50 80 ...

catB 40 90 ...

catC 90 100 ...

catA 20 30 ...

I want to find the max and min difference between the third and second columns.

I have the code:

```
mydict = {"catA":0, "catB":0, "catC":0} #...Dictionary is defined

for line in mydocument: 
    variable = line.split("\t")

    intvalue = int(variable[1])
    intvalue2= int(variable[2])
    intvalue_new = intvalue2-intvalue

    if variable[0] in mydict and mydict[variable[0]] < intvalue_new:
        mydict[variable[0]] = intvalue_new

print mydict
```

The code prints out mydict, but the fields are "0" at all values, as if the code didn't populate it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Most likely `variable[0]` is not what you expect it to be. You may want to use a `collections.defaultdict()` instead (`mydict = defaultdict(int)`) and skip the `variable[0] in mydict` part of your `if` test, which will add *all* possible first-column keys to show you what is going wrong.

Comment: Print out `variable` at each stage, see if it's what you think it should be.

Comment: How about adding `cat = variable[0].strip()` to remove any spaces and use `cat` variable in if check and the code below it.

Comment: I testet your code and got `{'catA': 30, 'catB': 50, 'catC': 10}` as result. Maybe you read the wrong file or something like this? How do you create `mydocument`? Do you iterate over `mydocument` twice?

Comment: Why are you calling `split("\t")`? If you do `split()` without arguments than the splits happens on every whitespace sequence and all empty strings are removed.

Comment: I printed out variables, and they are indeed what I expected them to be...Also, I perform other actions earlier in the code on the variables and those come out as expected. However, this is indeed my second iteration of mydocument...would that cause issues for me?

I should use defaultdict but I tried that at one point and ran into errors--I think I'm using an older version of python?

Comment: @Bakuriu: Perhaps there are columns with whitespace in the value?

Comment: @user2545406: you cannot iterate over a file twice. reopen the file or call `.seek(0)` to rewind to the start.